# how to check if existing column changes from some value to NULL using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to check the following condition using sql query using Oracle:

1. to check id a user changes Condition from some value to another value
2. to check if a user changes condition from some value to NULL

I am trying for the below query:

```
(select count(*) from MyTable where (:userconditionid = (select condition_id from MyTable 
where item = :useritem)) 
and  item = :useritem)
```

where :userconditioncode is the value user is trying to enter value, the above query works for normal values but it wont work for null value , if user changes the condition from some value to null value
the above sql query fails.

**Sample Data and Desired Results**
If user is trying to alter the condition_id to NULL
then I have to throw am error as follows:
"User are not allowed to change the value to null"

also if user is trying to alter the condition from NULL to some other value
then it should not throw an error.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I have provided the sample and desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly got all your comments - the only case to throw error for you is when not-null value is tried to be changed to null. Consider using

```
select case when condition_id is not null and :userconditionid is null then 1 else 0 end as do_throw_error
from MyTable
where item = :useritem
```

in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about nulls is that almost all '=' comparisons to null return false.

The proper test is not '=' but 'is null':

In P/L SQL:

```
if :userConditionCode is null then
    throw...
```

or is SQL:

```
(select count(*) from MyTable 
where 
( 
     (:userconditionid = (select condition_id from MyTable 
                          where item = :useritem)
     )
     or :userconditionid is null
) 
and  item = :useritem)
```

Comment: but is null wont work for the normal values, I need both in one query. so that I check for normal values also for null values

Comment: Was already adding s. See SQL example above - sorry about that!

Comment: As i said I dont want to throw an error if condition is already NULL and user will change to some value: but above sql fails for that

Comment: for example: if (select count(*) from MyTable 
where 
( 
     (:userconditionid = (select condition_id from MyTable 
                          where item = :useritem)
     )
     or :userconditionid is null
) 
and  item = :useritem) = 0 throw ...an error but i also want if exiting value if condition is  NULL then dont throw an error

Comment: two desired results:1) If user is trying to alter the condition_id to NULL then I have to throw am error as follows: "User are not allowed to change the value to null"

2) if user is trying to alter the condition from NULL to some other value then it should not throw an error.

Comment: You can't throw an error from a select statement. This check sounds like something you should do a) in a stored procedure (use the PL SQL I showed above) or b) in code before your code calls the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to check the value for null in SQL is `IS NULL` predicate. Of course, you can translate null to something else but real `NULL` check is nothing else than `IS NULL`.

Does this code suits your need? You've not wrote what should be done when there's no data for requested `:useritem`.

```
select 'User are not allowed to change the value to null' as msg
from MyTable
where item = :useritem
having (
    min(1) /*Table has that item*/,
    min(case
      when f.condition_id is not null and :userconditionid is null
      then 1
    end) /*User sets non null value to null*/
) in ((1,1))
```

Comment: @user2083356 Check my updated answer. The real case to check is "if user tries to update not null value to null", so no need for any other conditions. But "throw an error" should do your application by analyzing resultset or PL/SQL code with declared error code and not a SELECT statement.